# Change where gedit saves temp files

Tags: gedit

Looking for a way to put gedit's temporary tilde files in a different directory than the one I'm working in. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on the `External Tools` Plugin. It will automatically move the temporary file to a specific directory.

`Edit->Preferences->Editor`:

Disable Autosave files every X minutes if it is enabled.

`Edit->Preferences->Plugins`:

Enable `External Tools`.

`Tools->Manage External Tools...`:

1. Click on the `+` sign in the lower left corner to create a new tool.
2. Enter the name `Move temp files`.
3. In the textarea in the upper right corner paste the program below.
4. Click into the input field for `Shortcut key` and press Ctrl+S.
5. In the dropdown for `Save` select `Current Document`.
6. In the dropdown for `Output` select `Nothing`.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Moves the temporary backup file of the current document to a central directory.
   central_backup_dir="/tmp/gedit_tmp/" # Replace this with any directory you like.
   mkdir -p "$central_backup_dir"
   mv "${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH}~" "$central_backup_dir"
   ```

Comment: gedit forgets the shortcut on restart. You have to manually assign a different shortcut key combination, close the `Manage External Tools` dialog and set it to `Ctrl+s` everytime you restart gedit. This seems to be a bug in gedit. (Now I remember why I did not propose this solution the first time I came across this question.)